# get the private key for change addresses

Tags: private-key, change

Is it possible to get the private keys for change addresses that get generated?

I was wondering if there is a way to auto export that, do the clients make the change addresses or does another mechanism in the network make them?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do this by using the bitcoind JSON-RPC interface.

The following links should be helpful:

https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/API_reference_(JSON-RPC)
https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Original_Bitcoin_client/API_Calls_list

Identify the change address by looking at the transaction in question and then use "dumpprivkey ".

My understanding is that bitcoind is creating the change address every time you do a transaction where the change is greater than 0.0.